# Serial number to Phone number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a number like **5,24448E+11** in excel and i want to convert into france phone number like **+52444 137-4720** using excel formula.Please suggest some formula to convert it as phone number

Comment: Have you searched for the answer on Google? on here? You have asked a number of similar questions now and got good answers which will help you answer this question as well. We will be a lot less likely to help if you don't show that you've already tried to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Have a look at [How to ask good questions on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your question. Please provide us some actual issues to work on and what you have tried so far. I am trying to put it nicely, but SO is not dedicated to spoon-feed you answers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the cell where you entered the number
2. Right click on the cell then select the 'Format Cells' Option.
3. Select the number tab
4. Select Custom category
5. Enter the below format in the text box found below the Type:.

   ```
   +#####-###-####
   ```
6. Click OK

or if you want to use the formula, use the below formula in any cell, if you number is in the cell A1

```
 =TEXT(A1,"+#####-###-####")
```